# How to keep single quotes from confusing ksh -n

Tags: escaping, ksh

So I have a simple shell script called *try.sh*:

```
#! /bin/ksh

echo "'" | awk '

/'\''/ {
print "'\''ello, world"
}
'
```

and it runs fine:

```
$ ./try.sh  
'ello, world
```

But *ksh -n* is not altogether happy with it:

```
$ ksh -n ./try.sh
./try.sh: warning: line 3: ' quote may be missing
./try.sh: warning: line 5: ' quote may be missing
```

I can use tricks (awk variables, awk hex sequences, etc.) to make this go away, but surely there's some native elegant way to appease the ksh syntax checker (if nothing else, for the case when the embedded language has no provision for workarounds).  What am I forgetting?

[update: apparently the syntax checker is flagging the line because a quoted string with embedded newline is followed by another quoted string with no intervening white space.  David Korn says that he'll be reviewing the check for the next version of ksh.  See [the ast-users mailing list archives](http://lists.research.att.com/pipermail/ast-users/2012q3/thread.html#3541) for details.]

Comment: redirect stderr for the particular invocation to `2>/dev/null` ? ... I like things tidy too, but given the warning status, I would just live with this as 'a feature' ;-)... Good luck.

Comment: @shellter good idea, except the invocation is via a generalized rule for an installation (part of the base _nmake_ make rules for dealing with all shell scripts).  I could write a rule in the associated `Makefile` for this specific script, but that would offend my delicate sensibilities ;-)

Comment: Duplicated on the [ast-users] mailing list.

Comment: This is fundamentally a problem of mixing languages inside the same script.  In this case it's three layers deep: nmake->shell->nawk.
I go out of my way to to avoid such situations and keep things readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal snippet of code. IMO, passing a quote char in a variable is the most elegant way out of a nasty problem, as it avoids the quote/unquote pattern, and the awk code you see is the same as what awk gets to process.

```
$ echo "'" | 
   awk -v q=\'  'q { print q"Hello, world"q }'
'Hello, world'
```

The original question uses what I call the quote/unquote pattern, which is used a lot with other languages embedded in the unix shell.

The trick presents awk with a series of concatenated quoted and unquoted strings from the shell that together form a valid awk program text.  This makes code very hard to maintain, because you as a programmer, cannot see the valid awk code anymore.

Passing the special characters as variables to awk avoids this pattern.